# How does one navigate Ruby methods in VIM?

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm learning VIM for Rails development and would like to easily navigate methods in a file. So far I see several options:

- Find 'def' by using

  ```
  /def<space>
  ```
- Create a macro that corresponds to a key using q and record
- use VIM marks? (not even sure what they do, they just sound promising

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: I think the better way is using `]m` and `[m` also could you using `]M` to jump to the end of a method definition

Answer (score 42, accepted):

:help ]m

I think it requires [vim-ruby](http://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby) for ruby support.

Comment: I now use [ctags with git hooks](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html) and [fzf to jump to a tag in a current buffer](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples-(vim)#jump-to-tags-in-the-current-buffer). It works awesome but setting it all up is quite the ordeal.

Answer (score 36):

you'll want a feature called *ctags*

see [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), it works for many languages included Ruby and is v simple to use.

from VIM `:help ctags`

*ctags* will create an index of all identifiers in a source tree.  You can then use the tag commands to navigate around your source tree. see `:help tag-commands`.  The easiest is to place the cursor over a keyword and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>. To get back to where you came from press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

Beyond this you might want to look at this page which documents how to use VIM as a more full featured Ruby IDE: [Using Vim as a Complete Ruby On Rails IDE](http://biodegradablegeek.com/2007/12/using-vim-as-a-complete-ruby-on-rails-ide/)

Comment: Perfect! Also, for anyone else who's interested, there's plugin called SimpleFold that does arguably more useful folding than using the regular ruby folding (\f or ruby_fold = 1). Here's the link:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1868

Comment: ctags, plus the [Tag List](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) vim module works really well.

Comment: Big warning: Ctags does not properly parse Ruby files. For example, it does not accept class definition with four dots (e.g. class Xyz::Classname) and several other things. Unfortunately, latest version is from 2009 and even development version does not support that.

Comment: @lzap this is my issue, too.  Is there a better plugin?  ruby.vim doesn't do this either

Comment: Yes there is one amazing, Ruby 1.9+ only https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags - there is a pull request that improves CLI a bit. But the master works fine today.

Comment: exuberant ctags works perfectly for me. I also use this tags generator for C/C++ code

Answer (score 14):

Best solution for Vim: **use ctags**. Read Vim documentation about how to navigate in TAGS files, also install plugin like CtrlP which allows you to visually browse tags.

Warning: **Exuberant ctags does not work well with Ruby**, the parser is not in good condition and it has not been changed 4 years now.

- ctags doesn't deal with: module A::B
- ctags doesn't tag (at least some of) the operator methods like ==
- ctags doesn't support qualified tags, -type=+
- ctags doesn't output tags for constants or attributes.

Unfortunately all the others (I found 2) Ruby ctags generators are either outdated (no Ruby 1.9+ support) or very slow.

There is one solution tho. Ripper-ctags: https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags It is fast and it works as expected. It is based on Ruby 1.9+ feature called "Ripper" which allows us to build on top of (fast) Ruby original parser. It is **the most accurate ctags generator today**.

Ripper CLI options are almost identical to ctags, so if you already know ctags, you will find ripper-tags easy to learn. It's as easy as:

```
ripper-tags -R .
```

This creates TAGS file which vim automatically reads by default (must be the directory where you open your vim instance in, or manually change path setting in vim if you start it in a different directory - more in the Vim manual).

If you like this, you can go step further and install my project which **automatically creates TAGS for all the gems you install**: https://github.com/lzap/gem-ripper-tags

Usage is very simple (note again, only Ruby 1.9+):

```
gem install gem-ripper-tags
```

Then generate tags for all already installed gems:

```
gem ripper_tags
```

Anytime you install a gem now, tags will be automatically created.

```
gem instal some_gem ...
```

I go one additional step further - I have a git template which is regenerating my project TAGS **after every git pull or merge automatically** (using ripper-tags):

https://github.com/lzap/bin-public/blob/master/git-hooks-reinstall

Note you will need directory files/git_template as well from the very same git repository.

I hope this is good starting point for navigating in Ruby codebases :-)

Comment: Ctags, works best with static languages (because it's a basic static analyzer).

Comment: Sure, but it's very fast as you don't need to load up all the classes in memory and it is accurate enough. I work on many Ruby projects including quite large codebases and I get about 90 % correct results. Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of ideas:

Firstly, make a mapping to use the C function searching keys in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
:nmap [[ ?def <CR>
:nmap ]] /def <CR>
```

Then you can use `[[` and `]]` to go forward and back a function, just like in C/Perl/Java code etc.

Another way that might help:

In `.vimrc`, add the line:

```
:let ruby_fold = 1
```

Then use `zj`, `zk`, `z[` and `z]` to navigate by folds.  You could also install [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2275) so that you can easily delete folds using `daz`.

For finding specific functions (rather than just navigating around them) you'll want to use ctags (as mentioned by chillitom).  The [taglist plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) makes it much easier to navigate to a specific function, but (as chillitom said) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> are useful for following keywords under the cursor.

For more information, see:

```
:help [[
:help ft-ruby-syntax
:help z[
:help after-directory
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently found that Ruby.vim (per one of the answers above) comes with pretty useful key-bindings:

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<def\>','rubyDefine','b','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<def\>','rubyDefine','','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyDefine','b','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyDefine','','n')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [m :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<def\>','rubyDefine','b','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]m :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<def\>','rubyDefine','','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [M :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyDefine','b','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]M :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyDefine','','v')<CR>

nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<\%(class\<Bar>module\)\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','b','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<\%(class\<Bar>module\)\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','b','n')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','','n')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<\%(class\<Bar>module\)\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','b','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<\%(class\<Bar>module\)\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> [] :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','b','v')<CR>
xnoremap <silent> <buffer> ][ :<C-U>call <SID>searchsyn('\<end\>','rubyModule\<Bar>rubyClass','','v')<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to just search using '`/f methodName`'.

You should also look at turning on code folding by adding this line to your .vimrc:

```
:let ruby_fold
```

See `:help ft-ruby-syntax` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I just type the name of the method on the incremental search.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small shell script using `ag` (The Silver Searcher). Define the following functions in your `.vimrc`

This method will expand the word under the cursor.

```
function! SearchForDeclarationCursor()
  let searchTerm = expand("<cword>")
  call SearchForDeclaration(searchTerm)
endfunction
```

Then declare the `SearchForDeclaration` method

```
function! SearchForDeclaration(term)
  let definition = 'def ' . a:term
  cexpr system('ag -w ' . shellescape(definition))
endfunction
```

Note that we are explicitly searching for `def`  keyword. (You can use your language method signature syntax)

We then map the above function to a `Leader` command.

```
map <Leader>cd :call SearchForDeclarationCursor()<CR>
```

Now if you place your cursor anywhere on a method that is defined "in your project", and press `<Leader>cd`, it will navigate you to where the method is defined.

Note that a method can be defined in multiple classes. You can cycle using `<Leader>n` for next or `<Leader>p` for prev.

If you want a more detailed explanation for the above, I've written a blog post here: https://pradyumna.dev/articles/2017-12-17-search-ruby-method-declarations-in-vim

Hope this helps!